# Set a status for a discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I am trying to get my bot to have the status, `m!help`. I see that a lot of other bots have their help command in their status so I wanted to do that too.

```py
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="m!help"))
```

The above code is what I'm using, but it doesn't work. My code uses client.command if that helps.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? Could you please [edit] your question and also add a [mcve]?

Comment: Can you paste your entire code?

Answer (score 0):

try `@client.event` and you can use this to have a kinda animated status

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    client.statuses = cycle(['Hello','✨Bye'])
    change_status.start()
    print("Gangz Iz Herez")

@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def change_status():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=next(client.statuses)))
```

Comment: Where is `cycle()` and `next()` defined/imported?

Comment: @12944qwerty I believe `cycle()` is from the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module while `next()` is a normal python function.

Comment: @Makiyu Yes, I assumed as much (I thought `next()` was a itertools function too oops) but itertools is not imported in this code. I just wanted to make sure that AwJ knew this.

Comment: Yeah I just forgot to mention it...