# change bot status on interval: status wont change

Tags: python, discord.py

i wanted to create a loop of the status of my bot and change it from here and then, but it wont change

**my current code**
\

```py
from asyncio.tasks import sleep
import discord
import asyncio
import random

from discord import activity
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Game
from discord import guild
import time
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')
client.activity = discord.Activity(name="Todos os membros da Cyber$ell.", type=discord.ActivityType.watching)##first one
sleep(60)
client.activity = discord.Activity(name="Cyber$ell o MELHOR discord de vendas do ", type=discord.ActivityType.watching)##second one
sleep(60)
client.activity = discord.Activity(name="Cyber$ell Promoções em  BREVE?!", type=discord.ActivityType.watching)##third one
sleep(60)
client.activity = discord.Activity(name="Já descobriu oque vai comprar?, Cria o seu ticket então.", type=discord.ActivityType.watching)##last one and i dont know how to create a loop
sleep(60)
token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
client.run(token)
```

Comment: *Why* should it change? Have you maybe tried googling your question? There are plenty of solutions online, this is not even close to one of them. You're simply overwriting an attribute (not changing it in the API) *before* the bot actually runs.

Comment: yeah i tried it, but it doesn't work :(((

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67375785/set-a-status-for-a-discord-bot/67376310#67376310) you will find your anwser ...

Answer (score 0):

This will change ur bot status every 5sec

```
from discord.ext import tasks
from intertools import cycle

@client.event
async def on_ready(): 
    client.statuses = cycle(['Hello','✨Bye','UwU'])
    change_status.start()


@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def change_status():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=next(client.statuses)))
```